# Apache virtualhost with subdomain issue on windows server

Tags: windows, apache

Can someone help me with this issue please.
On my windows server, I have published a website made with wordpress with apache on port 80 (www.mysite.com).
On the other hand, I have another web site on the same server and it is published on IIS port 8001 (as localhost:8001).

I need my www.mysite.com/subsite subdomain to point to localhost:8001.
I have tried something like:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
 ServerName www.mysite.net
 ServerAlias mysite.net
 ProxyRequests on
 <Location />
   ProxyPass "http://localhost:8001/"
   ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8001/"
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried with:

```
<virtualHost *: 80>
      DocumentRoot \www\mysite\subsite
      ServerName "http://localhost:8001/"
</virtualHost>
```

In both cases it doesn't work for me.
Can someone help me please, I'm new to this apache configuration

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't enable [ProxyRequests](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) for a reverse proxy, this is only needed for a forward proxy (default is `Off`).

Remove the space before `80` and add `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.net
    ServerAlias mysite.net
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    ProxyPass        /subsite http://localhost:8001
    ProxyPassReverse /subsite http://localhost:8001
</VirtualHost>
```

I added `ServerAlias www.mysite.com` since you mentioned that this is your domain (or swap `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` with `www.mysite.net`).

If you want to proxy the requests only for `www.mysite.com`, you can use two VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.net
    ServerAlias mysite.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com

    ProxyPass        /subsite http://localhost:8001
    ProxyPassReverse /subsite http://localhost:8001
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also want to add logging using the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives (copy and adapt the lines from the default configuration).

You need to enable modules `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` in your server and restart Apache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply
I'm going to try now and give feedback
Best regards